# H2:How can i change csvread functionality by change h2 source code

Tags: java, sql, csv, h2

I have the following SQL code:

```
create table cross_links(sid varchar,tid varchar,snd int) 
as 
select * from csvread('csvfile')
```

I want to read csvfile twice. The second is exchange the position of sid and tid and then insert into the table. But it cost some performence, so I want to read it only once and the result is the same as read it twice.

How can I do it?

I think it must change the source code of H2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't need to do this. You can just write a simple CSV reader yourself that swaps or renames the columns as it reads them in.

Also, with your approach, you would also need to modify csvread to support different types of data - it only supports VARCHAR. That is going to be more work!